# How to detect if video had been sized up (Scaled up) in resolution?

Tags: ffmpeg

On Internet, I can see many videos/movies claim to have FHD (1920x1080) resolution, but on watching they seem to be shot in lower resolution and resized/scaled up using encoder or transcoding tool to 1080p resolution.

My question: is there any tool to detect such scaling up?
If possible, I prefer ffmpeg tool, or knowledge base of such detection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i rephrase your question as

> How natural does an image look?

If so, you are finding Naturalness Image Quality Evaluator (NIQE). Plz take a look of [Naturalness Image Quality Evaluator (NIQE) no-reference image quality score](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/images/ref/niqe.html). Then you may find some information from [Laboratory for Image & Video Engineering](https://live.ece.utexas.edu/research/Quality/index_algorithms.htm) and then you will get some tools like

- [scikit-video](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/measure.html)
- [Video Quality Indicators](http://vq.kt.agh.edu.pl/metrics.html)

Good Luck!